# Why do we need the subsets to be closed in this theorem?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The theorem in question is:

Let $X$ be Hausdorff and $\{F_1, F_2, ..., F_k\}$ a family of closed subsets of $X$. The subspace $F = \bigcup_{i=1}^k F_i$ of $X$ is compact if and only if all subspaces $F_i$ are compact.

I'm having trouble seeing why the $F_i$ need to be closed in this theorem. My rough proof is:

($\rightarrow$) For each $i=1, \ldots, k$ consider an open cover $C_i$ for $F_i$. Taking the unions of these open covers gives us an open cover for $F$. Since $F$ is compact by assumption, we have a finite open subcover for $F$ which yields finite open subcovers for each $F_i$ by using only the subcover sets that intersect each $F_i$.

I won't go into the other direction, as I have a feeling only this direction required the closed hypothsesis. Perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: Of course, in a proposition beginning "If the $F_i$ are compact, then...", we don't need to assume the $F_i$ are closed, because that's assumed in the first five words of the proposition. In the other direction you may need closedness.

Comment: Take $F_1=(0,1)$ and $F_2=[0,1]$ with the standard topology on $\mathbb R.$  Then $F_1\cup F_2$ is compact but $F_1$ is not.

Comment: @JackM well, that's not true unless your proposition contains the assumption "$X$ is Hausdorff".

Comment: Moreover, I would say even the direction you've shown needs work. You should show that one can avoid the case that for some $C_i$ the finite subcover of $F$ has an empty intersection with $C_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect.  If you want to prove $F_1$ is compact, you need to start with an arbitrary open cover $C_1$ of $F_1$ and find a finite subcover of it.  Your argument then chooses open covers $C_2,\dots,C_n$ of $F_2,\dots,F_n$ and finds a finite subcover $D\subseteq\bigcup C_i$.  However, $D$ is probably not a subset of $C_1$, so it does not give a finite subcover of $C_1$!  Even if you restrict to those elements of $D$ which intersect $F_1$, some of them may come from $C_i$ for $i>1$ rather than from $C_1$.

For an explicit counterexample, consider that $[0,1]$ is compact and is the union of any subset $C_1\subseteq [0,1]$ and $C_2=[0,1]$ no matter what $C_1$ is.  So your argument would prove that *every* subset of $[0,1]$ is compact, which is certainly false.

(On the other hand, the assumption that the $F_i$ are closed is not needed for the reverse direction.  Indeed, in any space, any finite union of compact subsets is compact.  Incidentally, the assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff is also unnecessary for both directions.)

Comment: I'm not choosing the open covers $C_i$... I'm assuming they are given and fixed.

Comment: But they _aren't_ given.  If you are proving $F_1$ is compact, you are given an open cover of $F_1$, but not of any of the other sets.  (In any case, this isn't the actual problem with your argument, since you _can_ choose open covers of the other sets.  But it's a sign that something is fishy since you have to make such an arbitrary choice.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Aren't they? He's proving each $F_i$ is compact, so he's given an open cover $C_i$ of each $F_i$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: No, because you need to prove _separately_ that each $F_i$ is compact.  For instance, imagine that actually $F_2$ had _no_ open covers at all.  Then it would not be correct to prove $F_1$ is compact by simultaneously looking at open covers of each $F_i$, since that is not possible so vacuously anything is true if you do that, even if $F_1$ might not actually be compact.  (This is not actually a real problem because any set does have some open cover, but it illustrates that you shouldn't think of it as being given covers of every $F_i$ at once.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't really understand what's wrong here.

Comment: I think I understand your objection now, but I still fail to see how to use the fact that the $F_i$ are closed to remedy the situation.

Comment: @theQman: Every closed subset of a compact space is compact.  The fact that the union of the $F_i$ is $F$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri . Consider $X=[0,3],\;$ $F_1=[0,2),\;$  $F_2=X.$  Let $C_1=\{[0,2-1/n): n\in \Bbb N\}$  and $C_2=\{X\}\;$  Then $C=C_1\cup C_2$ covers $F_1\cup F_2.$ Let  $D$ be a finite subcover of $C.$ ...... As  in the Q, let  $D_1= \{d\in D: d\cap F_1\ne \phi\}.$ .... Now $D$ must contain $(1,3]$ but  $(1,3]\cap F_1\ne \phi$  so $(1,3]\in D_1.$  But then $D_1$  is NOT a sub-cover of $C_1,$ as $D_1$ is not even a subset of $C_1$....Furthermore $D^*= D\setminus \{(1,3]\} \subset C_1$ but $D^* \subset [0,2-1/n)\}$  for some $n \in \Bbb N$ so $D^*$  is  not a cover of $F_1. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I understand that the proof provided by OP is not valid, and in fact I've posted such a comment directly to his question $3$ hours ago. What I don't understand is Eric's objection to the tackling of the $F_i$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are two compact subsets of a space $X$, then their union $A\cup B$ is also compact, without requiring $X$ to be Hausdorff or $A$ and $B$ closed. You need being Hausdorff of $X$ and closedness of the sets $F_i$ to prove the other direction.